# My question about Selenium's find element by css selector

Tags: java, string, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm using Selenium to find an web element by css selector. When I hard code it, it works fine like below.

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[aria-label=\"2018-10-17 Shared Google Drive Folder\"]")).getAttribute("data-id");
```

However, if I want to customize the css selector string based on date like below, it throws a error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
```

I print out the cssFormatString and it looks exactly the same as hard coded one above. Could anyone tell me where it went wrong?

```
// Customized cssFormatString code
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
String cssFormatString = "div[aria-label=\\\"" + strDate +  " Shared Google Drive Folder\\\"]";
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(cssFormatString)).getAttribute("data-id");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply use single quotes instead of double quotes, it should work.

```
String cssFormatString = "div[aria-label='2018-10-17 Shared Google Drive Folder']"
```

So your string concatination will be simple,

```
String cssFormatString = "div[aria-label='" + strDate +  " Shared Google Drive Folder']"
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to use single quotes instead of double quotes, for example:

`String cssFormatString = "div[aria-label='2018-10-17 Shared Google Drive Folder']"`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to construct a *cssSelector* using the value from `strDate` and the text **Shared Google Drive Folder** you can use the following solution:

```
// Customized cssFormatString code
Date date = new Date();
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String strDate = dateFormat.format(date);
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[aria-label^='" + strDate + "'][aria-label$='Shared Google Drive Folder']")).getAttribute("data-id");
```

Answer (score 0):

You code not work because you use unnecessary backslashes `\` 
Result of your code is `div[aria-label=\"2018-10-18 Shared Google Drive Folder\"]` and because of backslashes you get invalid selector error.
Use one backslash to escape quotes like in code below:

```
String cssFormatString = "div[aria-label=\"" + strDate +  " Shared Google Drive Folder\"]"
```

Value will be: `div[aria-label="2018-10-18 Shared Google Drive Folder"]`

Or use single quotes like in @Navarasu answer.

Comment: Thank you. I used single quotes

Comment: I don't know why but if I hard code the result of my initial code as you mentioned div[aria-label=\"2018-10-18 Shared Google Drive Folder\"], it actually worked.

Comment: If I use String cssFormatString = "div[aria-label=\"" + strDate +  " Shared Google Drive Folder\"]", although it looks the same as my initial code, it won't work.